# Mongoose.connect() - Environment Variables Best practices

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, environment-variables

I was wondering what code snippets you use, to connect to your DB via mongoose.

I tried different approaches.

- Building a connection string, based on the `node_env` and a number of other `env_vars` containing the credentials, the host, and the desired DB.
- using the `mongoose.connect {}` extra options object in which I passed my `env_vars`. This is also not clean since I still need the connection URL.

But both solutions are kind of a bodge, and I was wondering if there are any other ways, that you might know.

Comment: This is essentially a *"Do you like coke or pepsi?"* question, as opinions will greatly differ. IMHO you don't "hardcode" in real practice, but have a "configuration" to load which has such a connection string, and the "fallback" to that is generally coded to pickup from "environment" and then finally the default `localhost` and port expected by common deployment. Been doing that with every database for many many years now.

Comment: So in my case, using nodeJS, you would generate a JSON file during CI-Test for your test environment, which gets loaded by my application and is ignored by version control. If that fails, it falls back to a connection string from the environment.
And before deployment, my CI would generate a similar file for the production DBs?